# VIM: Clear mapping, autocmd and other effects from deleted plugin

Tags: vim

I recently removed python-mode plugin for some reason but its mappings and event calls are still intact for the buffers which I opened when the plugin was installed. Since no vim scripts from python-mode exits this displays error for certain events.

I used `:mapclear <buffer>` to clear the mappings but the event calls still exit. How can I clear them as well.

Update

I solved the problem by removing view files created by `restore_view` plugin.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't remove everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views and sessions by default persist the defined mappings, too. Where you're just using plugins (and seldom to never define ad-hoc mappings), this is superfluous; the plugin will re-define them on the next use, anyway.

To avoid this problem (and reduce the size of the corresponding files, remove the `options` value from the options:

```
:set sessionoptions-=options
:set viewoptions-=options
```